# jqGrid row update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

does anyone have a link to an asp.net mvc 2 c# sample which contains saving rows to the server? how do you post the results back to a db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out those two sample applications:

1. [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796)
2. [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC - Strongly typed helper](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741)

Comment: Despite the Razor part, first sample will work with ASP.NET MVC 2 out of the box. Just use WebForms view engine for your views and change references.