# jqGrid row update

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jqGrid row update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335766/jqgrid-row-update)

I am looking for an ASP.NET MVC 2 sample with a jqGrid update/insert to a database. How does the row gets posted to the server?

Answer (score 0):

it's done by ajax. it will call the page with get/post request, and pass the variables in

Answer (score 0):

Probably [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076834/jqgrid-editurl-controller-action-parameters/4077902#4077902) will help you. You can compare it with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917102/jqgrid-add-row-and-send-data-to-webservice-for-insert/3918615#3918615) which made for ASMX web services instead of ASP.NET MVC. You should return new rowid from the controller action in case of "add" operation. It's important mostly in the case of usage [reloadAfterSubmit:false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) option of the form editing.